# Is it possible to keep sockets open infinite time

Tags: java, c, sockets, network-programming

I'm new to network programming. I'm interested is it possible to establish network connection via sockets between Java server and C client and keep the connection open infinitely?
I want to keep the connection open to exchange XML data between the clients.

Comment: *"keep the connection open infinitely?"* Sadly no.  In just a few hundred million years, Earth will be vaporized.

Comment: No, eventually the universe will end :-)  On a more practical note, after some period of time the connection is likely to drop and have to be re-established due to a network issue.

Comment: Maybe you mean "persistent" instead of "infinite"?  "Infinite" brings out the cynical side in Stackoverflow. :P

Comment: @kevin628 either way, it's a weird question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is is theoretically possible to keep server sockets open an indefinitely long amount of time; however, it is not possible to do so with the client-side socket.  The main reason why is because the client side socket is dependent on the server side socket handling the data, and the server socket may close the connection.

While it might be possible to keep a connection open indefinitely, practical aspects typically ensure that such sockets don't stay open forever.  Network outages, misconfiguration in intermediate routers, exhaustion of bandwidth, lack of computing power, etc. all collude to ensure that point to point connections are at best temporary.

Note that a server side socket is a socket that receives requests to connect (spawning off connections which have their own return sockets), so it can be open even when there are no connections.  If you think of a socket as an open connection to another computer, you will need to reorient your thinking to have server sockets make any sense.

Comment: And don't forget to handle those pesky `EarthVaporizedException` and `UniverseHasEndedException` pointed out above.

Comment: @LucaGeretti Such commentary is fun, but really you're just avoiding answering the question.  Stackoverflow is not _meant_ to be boring, but answers that include the heat death of the universe are just not useful in a non-universal time scale.

Comment: The problem described in your first paragraph is not confined to the client socket. It is symmetrical. Either side can drop the connection, and so can any intermediate node.

Comment: @EJP A server socket doesn't close if the clients drop connections.  All connections can be lost on a server socket, but the socket itself remains.

Comment: so how long should a socket ideally be kept open for until a `reconnection` is required? (I'm still quite new to sockets)

Comment: Assuming vanilla HTTP, most client sockets are not reused.  The answer varies for other protocols, depending on the protocol.  For a lot of robust software, if the client program is not getting appropriate responses on the client side socket, closing the socket and reinitiating a connection is desirable.  It all depends on the details.  But I would not trust a socket without keep-alive characteristics that had been silent for more than five minutes, even though there's little justification in my time choice.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing is infinite (in computing), but you can keep a socket connection open as long as both applications are running.

Answer (score 2):

This is more a plea than an answer, but as a user I've found sockets drop all the time.  You can't keep them open indefintely.  When a socket closes unexpectedly, please (A) let the user know the connection has been dropped and (B) make it *real* easy to reestablish the *same* connection.  Okay, this involved games, but I've had clients that wouldn't admit the server was gone and servers that wouldn't recognise I was the same person as the one with the dropped connection.